# What kind of vector should I use to sample a cubemap?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am wondering if someone can provide some clarification.

I have a cubemap with a side of 8192 pixels for both width and height.

I am using the following vector (see below `dir_vector`)to sample my cubemap,

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec3 hangle; // horizontal angular range and increment
uniform vec3 vangle; // vertical angular range and increment
out vec3 dir_vector;


void main(){
   for (float theta = vangle.x; theta < float(vangle.y); theta+= vangle.z){
       for (float psi = hangle.x;  psi <  float(hangle.y); psi+= hangle.z){
           float x = sin(radians(theta)) * sin(radians(psi));
           float z = cos(radians(theta)) * sin(radians(psi));
           float y = cos(radians(theta));
           dir_vector = vec3(x,y,z);
       }
   } 
}
```

It is clear that `dir_vector` is going to have a length of 1 and x,y,z are going to be within (-1.0,1.0).

Would the length of the vector need to be greater given the size of my cubemap?

I am also assuming that given the coordinates of the `dir_vector` opengl already knows which side of the cubemap to sample. is this assumption correct?

Comment: "*I have a cubemap with a side of 8x1024 pixels width and height.*" No, you do not. Cubemaps *must* have square dimensions.

Comment: "*It is clear that dir_vector is going to have a length of 1*" hmph? Squaring x, y, and z and adding them together does not give 1. Are you sure you got x, y and z correct?

Comment: Hi @NicolBolas, it was poorly written. I meant that both sides are 8x1024. Just edited to make this clearer.

Comment: @newQOpenWid. It should be, this corresponds to a unitary vector described using spherical coordinates. The radius here is 1 so I do not include it.

Comment: @marcos: "*both sides are 8x1024.*" That doesn't make sense. How can a side have two dimensions? Do you mean 8 * 1024, or 8192? Because using the letter `x` there is generally how we denote multiple dimensions, not multiplication. That's `×`, which is not the letter `x`.

Comment: "It should be, this corresponds to a unitary vector described using spherical coordinates" That is wrong - the radius is ``sqrt(sin^2(radians(psi)) + cos^2(radians(theta)))``, not 1. Did you mean to put ``y = cos(radians(psi))`` instead of ``cos(radians(theta))``?

Comment: @newQOpenWid  I am using the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) with r set to 1 (See spherical to cartesian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is clear that dir_vector is going to have a length of 1 ...

You have a mistake in your code. If you're looking to convert from spherical coordinates, the formula for `y` should then be:

```
float y = cos(radians(psi));  // NOT theta
```

> Would the length of the vector need to be greater given the size of my cubemap?

No. OpenGL samples from a cubemap based on the direction of the vector, ignoring the length.

> I am also assuming that given the coordinates of the dir_vector opengl already knows which side of the cubemap to sample. is this assumption correct?

Yes. OpenGL determines the face of the cubemap based on the direction of the vector.

## Cubemap sampling

The details of cubemap sampling are described in section "8.13 Cube Map Texture Selection" of the [OpenGL spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf).

In short: The major axis is determined based on the coordinate of the largest magnitude. This is going to determine the cube-map face that's going to be sampled. The other two coordinates are divided by the major one, yielding values in the `[-1, 1]` range, then remapped to `[0, 1]` texture coordinates, which are then used to sample that face's texture like a regular 2d-texture.

For example, given the input vector `(10, 20, 100)`, the major axis is "positive z". OpenGL will calculate

```
s = (10/100 + 1)/2 = 0.55
t = (-20/100 + 1)/2 = 0.40
```

and sample the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z` face at coordinates (s, t). The conversion to an actual texel index will happen at this stage, taking the correct mipmap level into account.